# setAdapter does not work in fragment Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I used the same code in `Activity` and it works. But the same thing does not work in `Fragment`. I have placed some tests to check if the DB is created correctly and found the `cursor` is filled with data.

Here is the code:

```
public class Db_fragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    ListView listView;
    Db_listView_Adapter db_listView_adapter;

    public Db_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.db_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final MyDatabaseOpenHelper mDbHelper = new MyDatabaseOpenHelper(view.getContext());


        final EditText foodName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameForDb);
        Button enterData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.enterData);
        Button showData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.showData);

        enterData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SQLiteDatabase myDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                 ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.FOOD_NAME,foodName.getText().toString());
                long newRowId ;
                newRowId = myDb.insert(TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
                Log.e("TEST1","TEST INSERT " + String.valueOf(newRowId));

            }
        });

        showData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SQLiteDatabase myDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                String[] projection = {"_id",TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.FOOD_NAME};

                Cursor c = myDb.query(
                        TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );

                Log.e("TEST3", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
                listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbView);
                db_listView_adapter = new Db_listView_Adapter(view.getContext(),c);
                listView.setAdapter(db_listView_adapter);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The app crashes on this line :

```
listView.setAdapter(db_listView_adapter);
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `findViewById` of the `dbView` from the `onClickListener` of `showData` and place it in the `onCreateView`.

So remove the following.

```
showData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // ... Remove the following code segment from here. 
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbView); 
        db_listView_adapter = new Db_listView_Adapter(view.getContext(),c);
        listView.setAdapter(db_listView_adapter);

    }
});
```

Place the code segment in your `onCreateView` function.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.db_fragment, container, false);

    // Place the code segment here
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbView); 
    db_listView_adapter = new Db_listView_Adapter(view.getContext(),c);
    listView.setAdapter(db_listView_adapter);

    return view;
}
```

It works in your `Activity` as you don't have find the `ListView` id in the `View` returned. Once you set the content view of your `Activity` you can place `findViewById` anywhere and it'll find the associated layout reference perfectly.

In case of `Fragment`, as you see the `onCreateView` function returns a `View` object as the reference of the `View` which is inflated. So you need to find your `ListView` in that `View`. That's why you need to put `view.findViewById` to search for reference id of the `ListView` in that `View` which is inflated.

When you're putting the `listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbView);` inside the `showData.setOnClickListener` it gets the reference of the button `showData` and tries to find the `dbView` in that `Button` view which causes the error.

So its necessary to get the reference of your list inside `onCreateView` and set the adapter there. You can then easily call `notifyDatasetChanged()` to reload your list when the `cursor` is filled with data.

By the way, you may put the code segment in your `onViewCreated` function too as you see you could get the reference of the `showData` button from there without any problem. So you can even put the code segment there too.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final MyDatabaseOpenHelper mDbHelper = new MyDatabaseOpenHelper(view.getContext());


    final EditText foodName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameForDb);
    Button enterData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.enterData);
    Button showData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.showData);

    // You can place the code segment here too
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbView); 
    db_listView_adapter = new Db_listView_Adapter(view.getContext(),c);
    listView.setAdapter(db_listView_adapter);

    // ... Other code goes here. 
}
```

And you might modify the `showData.setOnClickListener` like this

```
showData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SQLiteDatabase myDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            String[] projection = {"_id",TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.FOOD_NAME};

            Cursor c = myDb.query(
                    TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );

            Log.e("TEST3", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));

            // Call notifyDatasetChanged when the cursor is filled with data to load the list. 
            db_listView_adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

        }
    });
```